# Can I exploit Google's implementation of getting the user location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Ok the answer to my question is probably rather simple so let's get to it:

**Is it possible to get the user's location directly from the Google Map like the `myLocationLayer` does it?**

To be a bit more precise: I know that there are various possibilities to get the user location and that they are explained wonderfully in [answers here on SO like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655). But the Maps API v2 seems so simple and it has so many nice gettters and setters that I can't but wonder if there isn't one to just set

```
GoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.goToUserLocation());
```

and let Google handle the satellite and network part. They already **have** the location (you can click on the `myLocationsButton` and go there immediately) so I would be rather suprised if this is not possible programmatically... But I did not find anything in the [API v2 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map).

Thanks very much for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`GoogleMap.getMyLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation%28%29). Note that it is depracted, but IMHO it should not be.

Comment: Ok +1 for pointing out how blind I actually am, but I think the "true" answer would be an implementation of the `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` which they recommend instead... I'm going to look into this a bit more and then come back to you. Thanks

Comment: @avalancha It is also stated there that `LocationClient` `"is used by the "My Location" blue dot"`, so if you use `getMyLocation` you are using `LocationClient` indirectly. That's why I don't think it should be deprecated.

Comment: you're probably right, they should declare it a convenience method that can be used under certain circumstances